# ImagePicker when clicked nothing happens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here's the code

I'm trying to deploy ImagePicker via React Native. When I log at the beginning of the function, it prints, but when I try to log permissionResult nothing happens. I deployed the same code on a separate project, it worked just fine.

Please tell me what I did wrong here

```
const defaultImageUri = 'https://cdn.orvis.com/images/DBS_Bichon_1280.jpg';

export default function Screen2({ navigation }) {
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = React.useState(defaultImageUri);

  var pickImage = async () => {
    var permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(permissionResult);
    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      console.log('permission to access camera roll is required!');
      return;
    }

    var result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImageUri(result.uri);
    }
  };
```

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-paper": "3.6.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.14.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "*",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.11",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "6.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons": "6.6.0"
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by updating the version of Expo from 35 to 37. I faced a lot of bugs that arise from Expo version. So I need to keep an eye on it all the time.